# Sending text JSON over node.js socket how to deal with '\n\r' simbols

Tags: json, node.js, sockets

I have client - server application, server side on Node.js client on flash, communicating with each other by socket. I write stringifyed JSON to socket, and on server read data:

```
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString());
        var json = JSON.parse(data.toString()) });
```

Everything was OK, until I started to send to server JSON with long text messages containing '\n\r'. On that I getting error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

because '\n\r' means end of the pack. Delete '\n\r' from text isn't the good way cause I need it to show text correctly. Please give me best way to deal with that problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way would be to `try` to parse, if not, then wait for more data:

```
var json = '';

socket.on('data', function(data) {
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        json += data;

        try {
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            // Now it's fine.
        } catch (e) {
            // Wait for more.
            return;
        }
    }

    // Now it's fine.
    // At the end do;
    json = '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot I think it's easiest and best approach, works fine even with several '\n\r'.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify(data)` instead of `.toString()`